# Display even numbers from a range in the tkinter Spinbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to display the even numbers from a range between 0 and 1000 in a spinbox.

Below is the following code :

```
Spinbox(root, from_ = 0, to = 1000, textvariable = year).pack()
```

How can I modify such that only the even numbers between 0 and 1000 is displayed in the spinbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Spinbox` will accept an explicit list of values:

```
Spinbox(values=(1, 10, 100, 1000))
```

Of course, you don't want to enumerate all the evens from 0 to 1000, use `range`, starting at 0 and with a step of 2:

```
Spinbox(values=list(range(0, 1000+1, 2))).pack()
```